# Encryption with Node Crypto - Decryption with PHP openssl_decrypt fails

Tags: php, node.js, encryption, jwt

I'm trying to create a JWT (JSON web token) in a node service which then needs to be checked in a PHP service.

I'm creating the token as per the [spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519) as far as I can tell, and I'm encrypting the signature with the Node [crypto](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html) library. I've read that the only algorithm that'll work reliably between these technologies is `aes-128-cbc` so that's the one I'm using.

I had some luck using `mcrypt_decrypt`, but it was still not 100% correct which is still a fail. Also because that library is deprecated I'd rather use `openssl_decrypt`, which I cannot get to work at all, it simply returns false.

The secret and init vector are both stored in a database in fields of type varchar(16), so they are the same in both bits of code. I'm using a 16byte blocksize so matching that with 16byte secret and iv.

I've tried different combinations of binary, hex and base64 formats but cannot get the openssl_decrypt function to return anything but false.

This question comes down to how can I encrypt a string in node and decrypt it in PHP? Or what is wrong with my current usage of these methods?

Node v7.4.0

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var secret = crypto.randomBytes(16);
var iv = crypto.randomBytes(16);
var header = { type:'JWT', alg: 'aes-128-cbc' };
var payload = { iss: 'auth-token', exp: Date.now() + 86400, token: <some uuid> };

var data = new Buffer(JSON.stringify(header)).toString('base64') + '.' + new Buffer(JSON.stringify(payload)).toString('base64');
var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-128-cbc', secret, iv);
var encrypted = cipher.update(data, 'utf8', 'base64') + cipher.final('base64');
var JWT = data + '.'+ encrypted;
```

PHP v7.0.13 (also tried v7.1.1)

```
list($header64, $payload64, $sigEnc) = explode('.', $_POST['jwt']);
$header = base64_decode ($header64);
$payload = base64_decode ($payload64);
$signature = openssl_decrypt($sigEnc, 'aes-128-cbc', $secret, null, $iv); // secret and iv are both straight out of the database
```

**Update**

I've changed my objective here now and used a hash, which is possibly the correct way. So in the Node service I create a SHA256 hash of the base64 header and payload using a random key stored in the database. Then in the PHP service I do the same and compare the hashes. This is a better approach, which I should have taken before.

But there is still the question of how can you reliably encrypt a string in Node and decrypt it in PHP?

Comment: There must be libraries that properly implement the spec. Have you checked on both sides?

Comment: There are libraries but they seem a little overkill for what should be fairly straightforward.

Comment: How about a sample plaintext, key, iv, and ciphertext from your application so we can check your work? Also are you the FITH CoinOp, or a different one?

Comment: The issue could be anywhere like the encoding of key and IV. You should provide some example inputs and outputs. Also, why are you using AES-CBC as a sort-of MAC? By doing that, you may be providing a decryption oracle for attackers through a padding oracle attack. You should use proper MACs like HMAC.

Comment: I'm under the impression if you want 2 way encryption between Node and PHP then aes-128-cbc is the most reliable algorithm to use. But yes using a hash made more sense, in the end.

Answer (score 0):

> There are libraries but they seem a little overkill for what should be fairly straightforward.

It should be fairly straightforward but apparently it isn't.

With cryptography you either understand it well enough to implement the algorithms yourself from scratch, or you don't try because it's too risky to get it wrong. It's bad enough when you make a mistake like you did when nothing works, but it is way worse when it seems to work but is weak and vulnerable to some attack that you didn't think about.

If you're serious about security then use the right tool for the job. In Node you have:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwt
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwt-simple
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-jwt

and [many more](https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/jwt).

For PHP you have:

- https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt
- https://github.com/namshi/jose
- https://github.com/lcobucci/jwt
- https://github.com/emarref/jwt
- https://github.com/Spomky-Labs/jose
- https://github.com/nov/jose-php

See https://jwt.io/ for more info, more tools and more tutorials.

If you want to learn how to do it correctly yourself without using a library, then read the source code of those libraries - they are all open source, free software.

Comment: The fact I'm using JWT isn't that important. I'm more asking what is the best method to encrypt a string in node and decrypt it in PHP? I was hoping there shouldn't be need for a library for this as both languages have encryption and decryption methods. I am not talking about creating a new form of encryption myself, just using the methods that are already available.